# Explain what this SQL Split function does

Tags: sql

I am fairly new at SQL. I found this script on the web. It does a great job at splitting string values with delimiter values.

I can see they declared two variables. Everything after that is does not mean much to me. Could someone walk me through how fn_split_string_to_column work?

I can't stress this enough. I am fairly new at this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split_string_to_column] (
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS @out_put TABLE (
    [column_id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @pos INT = 0,
        @len INT = 0

    SET @string = CASE 
            WHEN RIGHT(@string, 1) != @delimiter
                THEN @string + @delimiter
            ELSE @string
            END
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + 1) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @len = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + 1) - @pos
        SET @value = SUBSTRING(@string, @pos, @len)

        INSERT INTO @out_put ([value])
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@value)) AS [column]

        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + @len) + 1
    END 
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: Hi please atleast tell us what you understand at present ?  Or, which part you are confused with ? As for start see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4884/sql-server-2016-stringsplit-function/)

Comment: Aside: Curious thing that it splits an `NVarChar` string based on occurrences of a `Char`, not an `NChar`.

Comment: Hey @user716255, have you gotten a satisfactory answer below?  If so, consider voting one up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it does is take a string, such as 'lets, do, this', and returns a table with the results being an indexing of the terms of the string split by a given character.

Use it like this:

```
select    column_id, value
from      fn_split_string_to_column('lets, do, this', ',');
```

Though more often it's part of a larger query:

```
select        st.col1, 
              st.col2,   
              termOrder = sp.column_id, 
              term = sp.value
from          someTable st
cross apply   fn_split_string_to_column(st.colToSplit, ',') sp;
```

Note that sql server 2016 has a built in split function, though it won't give you the term ordering (and order is not guaranteed), and it won't trim the entries:

```
select * from string_split('lets, do, this', ',');
```

As to how this actually works, here is a commented version of the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split_string_to_column] (
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), -- the string to be splitted
    @delimiter CHAR(1) -- the character that tells you where to make the cuts
)
-- The result set will be a table, not a scalar value
RETURNS @out_put TABLE (
    [column_id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, -- where the term occured in the string
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX) -- the splitted term
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE 
        @value NVARCHAR(MAX), -- holds the value of each segment (split in the string, result of substring) 
        @pos INT = 0, -- determines the starting position of a segment (for use in substring)
        @len INT = 0 -- determines the length of the segment (for use in substring)

    -- Ensure the passed-in string always ends with the delimiter character
    -- This is so that the loop doesn't terminate prematurely
    SET @string = 
        CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(@string, 1) != @delimiter THEN @string + @delimiter
        ELSE @string
        END


    -- while the length of the next segment would be positive ...
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + 1) > 0 
    BEGIN

        -- ... establish the length of the next segment to analyze
        SET @len = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + 1) - @pos 

        -- ... get the next segment to analyze
        SET @value = SUBSTRING(@string, @pos, @len) 

        -- ... insert the segment as an entry into the results, ensuring it has no spaces surrounding it
        INSERT INTO @out_put ([value])
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@value)) AS [column]

        -- ... in advance of the next loop, establish the starting position of the next segment
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + @len) + 1

    END 
    RETURN

END
```

Answer (score 2):

It takes a string like "list,of,items" and a delimiter character (',' in this case) and returns a table with the items on separate, numbered rows

i.e.

```
1  list
2  of
3  items
```